# Python Pdoc - how to export html with separate css file?

Tags: python, css, pdoc

I am using pdoc function:

```
def html(module_name, docfilter=None, allsubmodules=False, external_links=False, link_prefix='', source=True)
```

But according to documentation on [http://pdoc.burntsushi.net/pdoc#pdoc.html](https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html) I am unable to find out how to export HTML separated from CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Pdoc uses a [*html.mako* template file](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/blob/d8602fcf7238de412e8be6e28c31f48f1d858ce3/pdoc/templates/html.mako#L350-L355) that includes CSS stylesheets. To change CSS, one needs to either copy and modify the whole HTML template, or override [just the included *head.mako*](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#custom-templates) to include additional styles. In either case one then needs to run pdoc with `--template-dir` switch:

```
$ pdoc --html --template-dir=my_templates my_project
```